# Scroll widget vertically

Tags: c++, qt

Plesae, how can I scroll widget using gridlayout ( this has many child)

Thank you ?

```
 MyGrid->addWidget(CareState,lig,col);

            while (MyQuery->next())
            {
                 col++;
                CareState = new Care_state();

                CareState->LbMileage->setText("N° matricule: "+MyQuery->value(1).toString());
                CareState->LbMileage->setFont(QFont("C059",17,(font().bold())));
                CareState->LbMileage->setFont(QFont("Lato Black",17,(font().bold())));
                CareState->Lbmodel->setText("Modèle: "+MyQuery->value(2).toString());
                CareState->Lbmodel->setFont(QFont("Lato Black",17,(font().bold())));
                CareState->Lbmarque->setText("Marque: "+MyQuery->value(3).toString());
                CareState->Lbmarque->setFont(QFont("Lato Black",17,(font().bold())));
                CareState->Lbstate->setText(MyQuery->value(5).toString());
                CareState->Lbstate->setFont(QFont("Lato Black",17,(font().bold())));
                if(MyQuery->value(5).toString()=="Non disponible")
                {CareState->Lbstate->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("color: rgb(253, 252, 254);}

                MyGrid->addWidget(CareState,lig,col);

                if(col==3){col=0;lig=lig+1;}

            }
                MyWidget->scroll(0,0);
                MyWidget->showMaximized();
            }
```

This is my grid who contains my elemnts..
Please, help me to scroll it .
Thank you so much!

Comment: Put your grid layout in [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add child widget in scroll area and set scroll area in layout. Here below is working example for your problem:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QScrollArea>
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    //creating ui elements
    QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
    QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");

    //creating child widget to be scrolled
    QWidget *childWidget = new QWidget(this);
    childWidget->setMinimumSize(500,500);

    //scroll area for child widget
    QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
    scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
    scrollArea->setWidget(childWidget);
    scrollArea->setVisible(true);

    // layout for parent widget
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button1,0,0);
    layout->addWidget(button2,0,1);
    layout->addWidget(scrollArea,2,0,1,2,Qt::AlignCenter);
    setLayout(layout);

    //creating child ui elements
    QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
    QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four");
    QGridLayout *childlayout = new QGridLayout;

    // layout for child widget
    childlayout->addWidget(button3,0,0);
    childlayout->addWidget(button4,0,1);
    childWidget->setLayout(childlayout);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}
```